# Помогите с построением таблицы на PHP на 3 столбца

Tags: php, массивы, консоль, таблицы

Я новичок, необходимо построить массиви вывести значения в таблицу используя PHP, для вывода ее в терминал (консоль).
3 столбца (имя,фамилия,номер телефона)
Допустим, 3 значения (Антон Сидоров 0955554433, Вова Соколов 0665554422, Анна Смирнова 0776665544)
Как отобразить это в консоле в виде таблицы с колонками:(имя,фамилия,номер телефона) ???

Буду рад любым подсказкам.

---

[image: Должно получиться что-то вроде этого]

```
<?php $array = [ [ 'name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Sidorov', 'phone' => '0958887766' ], [ 'name' => 'Anna', 'last_name' => 'Popovic', 'phone' => '0967778899' ], [ 'name' => 'Vova', 'last_name' => 'Sokolov', 'phone' => '0976663322' ], ];
```

К примеру, вот данные, как дальше быть?)

Должно получиться что-то вроде этого

Comment: Надо перебрать массив и найти длину самой длинной строки в каждой колонке. А дальше снова в цикле, используя str_pad()

Comment: еще границы псевдографикой нарисовать можно )

Comment: длину заголовков таблицы тоже надо учитывать при подсчете макс. длины